# What is meant by "stable training" of a deep learning model?

Tags: deep-learning, training, deep-neural-networks, computational-learning-theory, stability

I have read it said that the "stable training" of a deep learning model is important. What is meant by "stable training" of a deep learning model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can say "[Stable Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_(learning_theory))" of a supervised machine learner is as follows:

> A stable learning algorithm is one for which the prediction does not change much when the training data is modified slightly.

You can follow [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_(learning_theory)) to know more in details about how can we measure the stability in the context of computational learning theory.