# Is stability an attribute of model or training algorithm used or combination of both?

Tags: neural-networks, training, stability

From [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/28024/18758) answer, stability is attributed to a learning algorithm

> A **stable learning algorithm** is one for which the prediction does not
> change much when the training data is modified slightly.

At some other places, I read the phrase "stability of neural network model". I am not sure whether the stability of a learning algorithm and the stability of a model are the same or not. If same then

> A **stable model** is one for which the prediction does not
> change much when the training data is modified slightly.

Is it true? If not, is there anything called stability of a model and is different from the stability of a learning algorithm?

Suppose I am training a neural network model with a gradient descent algorithm. For which one, do I need to attribute stability or instability? Is it to the neural network model or to the gradient descent training algorithm? Or it should be attributed to the combination of both?

Comment: is one for which the prediction does not change much when the training data is modified slightly. Is example back to do it again

Comment: @Rachrachben Do you mean it applies to both model and training algorithm?

Comment: Can you provide a source for the second part(stable model) as well?  The answer you refer to cites a Wikipedia article which gives a list of [stable learning algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_(learning_theory)#Algorithms_that_are_stable). Neither gradient descent nor neural networks are on the list.